# php sql merge 2 queries

Tags: sql, join, union

I have 2 queries one straight after the other:

```
$sql_result8 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM properties WHERE c4='$id'", $db); $charges = mysql_num_rows($sql_result8); 
$sql_result8 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE c4='$id'", $db); $charges = $charges + mysql_num_rows($sql_result8);
```

What kind of query would I need to merge these? Some kind of JOIN? UNION?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM properties p, vehicles v WHERE p.c4 = v.c4 AND p.c4 = '$id'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM properties JOIN vehicles USING (c4) WHERE c4='$id'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just find out the number or rows returned from both queries and not show the actual columns, you can use this:

```
$sql_result8 = mysql_query(
    "SELECT 
         ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM properties WHERE c4='$id' )
       + ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vehicles WHERE c4='$id' )
    ", $db );
```